# Running PHP for template files loaded from XML as DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, model-view-controller, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I'm writing my own little MVC framework that loads template files based on a layout.xml file(s) that specifies which template files to load where. This way existing pages can be easily extended or modified through XML and new (phtml) template files.

To do this I'm using *DOMDocument* objects to load template files into the right HTML elements. This is working properly now, however I just realized PHP contents of template files will simply be interpreted as plain HTML when converting it to a DOMDocument.

How do I cope with this the right way? I figured I'd execute the PHP from template files using **eval()**, then insert the resulting HTML into the DOMDocument object. However, I'd rather avoid using *eval* because of its bad image (dangerous and heavy?). It seems like exactly what I'm looking for though.

If anyone could give me some advice about this issue it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think Twig translates the templates to a PHP file and then runs the PHP file to generate the output, you could do a similar process.  This allows you to cache the generated templates as well which will reduce parse time.  So rather than executing individual segments of the PHP, you could do something like...

```
// Create temporary file (must have .php extension)
$fh = fopen ( "a.php", "w");
// Write out generated HTML
fwrite($fh, '<SomeTag>Content</SomeTag>'.PHP_EOL);
// Add in PHP code where necessary
fwrite($fh, '<?php'.PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fh, '$a="1";'.PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fh, 'echo $a;'.PHP_EOL);
fwrite($fh, '?>'.PHP_EOL);
fclose($fh);

// Run the generated file
require "a.php";
```

If you want to capture the output, then use the output buffering...

```
ob_start();
require "a.php";
$html = ob_get_clean();

echo $html;
```